# Image not showing on Product Page. Fotorama issue on Magento 2.3x

Tags: magento2, fotorama

The theme dev on this, Land of Coder, has gone ghost again on support of this after they said they were in there fixing it, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

Straightforward issue. Visit http://m2.vulcansrest.com/socknado-naked-orchid.html and you'll see the arrows in the place of the product image. The image in present for this product and marked base, thumb, and swatch. There is an error in inspector of:

Uncaught TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function
at UiClass.initGallery (gallery.js:297)
at UiClass.initialize (gallery.js:139)
at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
at UiClass (class.js:49)
at main.js:31
at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
at Object.context.execCb (resolver.js:145)
at Module.check (require.js:866)
at Module. (require.js:1113)
at require.js:132

They asked me first to replace jquery.zoom.min.js  with a new version then run:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean

I did this on both the theme and the child theme, which I am running.

They then asked me to replace gallery.phtml with a new version they provided, then clear cache. I did this on both theme and child. Still same issue.

I then tried:

1. I removed the code at line 297 referencing fotorama in lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.js This is    the file I am 99% sure is the functioning gallery.js.
   The other gallery.js that had the same fotorama code at line 297 was located at   vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.js.
   When I made the changes in this file and ran the appropriate commands, it changed nothing, and that's why I am fairly certain the lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.js
   is the file in control here.

2  When made the change at 297, it then gave me this error in Console at line 490:
gallery.js:460 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOptions' of null
at Object.updateOptions (gallery.js:460)     at Object.exit (gallery.js:355)
at mqChange (matchMedia.js:133)     at window.mediaCheck (matchMedia.js:143)
at gallery.js:322     at Function.m.each.m.forEach (underscore.js:153)
at UiClass.setupBreakpoints (gallery.js:321)
at UiClass.initialize (gallery.js:141)
at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
at UiClass (class.js:49)

I went down this rabbit hole and it kept throwing critical errors associated with fotorama, and I'm stuck. I tried removing the next lines it stated were the issues, but it just led to more issues.

Can you please give me the real fix for this problem?

Any clue on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!